# Displaying rectangles in game window with XNA

Tags: c#, grid, xna, rectangles

I want to divide my game grid into an array of rectangles. Each rectangle is 40x40 and there are 14 rectangles in every column, with a total of 25 columns. This covers a game area of 560x1000.

This is the code I have set up to make the first column of rectangles on the game grid:

```
Rectangle[] gameTiles = new Rectangle[15];

for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
{
    gameTiles[i] = new Rectangle(0, i * 40, 40, 40);
}
```

I'm pretty sure this works, but of course I cannot confirm it because rectangles do not render on the screen for me to physically see them. What I would like to do for debugging purposes is to render a border, or fill the rectangle with color so I can see it on the game itself, just to make sure this works.

Is there a way to make this happen? Or any relatively simple way I can just make sure that this works?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 23):

First, make a 1x1 pixel texture of white for the rectangle:

```
var t = new Texture2D(GraphicsDevice, 1, 1);
t.SetData(new[] { Color.White });
```

Now, you need to render the rectangle - assume the Rectangle is called `rectangle`. For a rendering a filled block, it is very simple - make sure to set the tint `Color` to be the colour you want. Just use this code:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(t, rectangle, Color.Black);
```

For a border, is it more complex. You have to draw the 4 lines that make up the outline (the rectangle here is `r`):

```
int bw = 2; // Border width

spriteBatch.Draw(t, new Rectangle(r.Left, r.Top, bw, r.Height), Color.Black); // Left
spriteBatch.Draw(t, new Rectangle(r.Right, r.Top, bw, r.Height), Color.Black); // Right
spriteBatch.Draw(t, new Rectangle(r.Left, r.Top, r.Width , bw), Color.Black); // Top
spriteBatch.Draw(t, new Rectangle(r.Left, r.Bottom, r.Width, bw), Color.Black); // Bottom
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfect if you want to draw rectangles over your existing textures. Great when you want to test/see for collisions

http://bluelinegamestudios.com/blog/posts/drawing-a-hollow-rectangle-border-in-xna-4-0/

**-----From Site-----**

The basic trick to drawing shapes is to make a single-pixel texture which is White, which you can then mix with other colors and display in solid shapes.

```
// At the top of your class:
Texture2D pixel;

// Somewhere in your LoadContent() method:
pixel = new Texture2D(GameBase.GraphicsDevice, 1, 1, false, SurfaceFormat.Color);
pixel.SetData(new[] { Color.White }); // so that we can draw whatever color we want on top of it
```

Then in your Draw() method do something like:

```
spriteBatch.Begin();

// Create any rectangle you want. Here we'll use the TitleSafeArea for fun.
Rectangle titleSafeRectangle = GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea;

// Call our method (also defined in this blog-post)
DrawBorder(titleSafeRectangle, 5, Color.Red);

spriteBatch.End();
```

And the actual method that does the drawing:

```
private void DrawBorder(Rectangle rectangleToDraw, int thicknessOfBorder, Color borderColor)
{
    // Draw top line
    spriteBatch.Draw(pixel, new Rectangle(rectangleToDraw.X, rectangleToDraw.Y, rectangleToDraw.Width, thicknessOfBorder), borderColor);

    // Draw left line
    spriteBatch.Draw(pixel, new Rectangle(rectangleToDraw.X, rectangleToDraw.Y, thicknessOfBorder, rectangleToDraw.Height), borderColor);

    // Draw right line
    spriteBatch.Draw(pixel, new Rectangle((rectangleToDraw.X + rectangleToDraw.Width - thicknessOfBorder),
                                    rectangleToDraw.Y,
                                    thicknessOfBorder,
                                    rectangleToDraw.Height), borderColor);
    // Draw bottom line
    spriteBatch.Draw(pixel, new Rectangle(rectangleToDraw.X,
                                    rectangleToDraw.Y + rectangleToDraw.Height - thicknessOfBorder,
                                    rectangleToDraw.Width,
                                    thicknessOfBorder), borderColor);
}
```